# error: no '' member function declared in class 'SonarSRF08'

Tags: arduino-mega, c++

Hi, I am a pretty novice coder and I am getting this error consistently with a library I have installed. Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SonarSRF02.h>
#include <SonarSRF08.h>

#define leftAddress ( 0xF2 >> 1)
#define rightAddress ( 0xE0 >> 1)
#define mainAddress ( 0xF8 >> 1)
SonarSRF02 LeftSonar;
SonarSRF02 RightSonar;
SonarSRF08 MainSonar;

char unit = 'c'; // 'i' for inches, 'c' for centimeters, 'm' for micro-seconds

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);

    LeftSonar.connect(leftAddress);
    Serial.println("Left SRF02 US-Sensor ");
    Serial.println(LeftSonar.getSoft());

    RightSonar.connect(rightAddress);
    Serial.println("Right SRF02 US-Sensor ");
    Serial.println(RightSonar.getSoft());

    MainSonar.connect(mainAddress);
    Serial.println("Main SRF08 US-Sensor ");
    Serial.println(MainSonar.getSoft());
}

void loop() {
    float sensorReading = 0;

    sensorReading = LeftSonar.getRange(unit);
    // print out distance
    Serial.print("Distance from left: ");
    Serial.print(sensorReading);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(unit);
    Serial.println();

    sensorReading = RightSonar.getRange(unit);
    // print out distance
    Serial.print("Distance from right: ");
    Serial.print(sensorReading);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(unit);
    Serial.println();

    sensorReading = MainSonar.getRange(unit);
    // print out distance
    Serial.print("Distance from main: ");
    Serial.print(sensorReading);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(unit);
    Serial.println();
}
```

My project is using an SRF08 sensor with an Arduino Mega 2560

Answer (score 3):

**Please note that I did not try to run your code on my Mega because I don't have SRFs**

However, here is what I tried to recreate your error:

- I went to the arduino homepage and downloaded the 1.0.5 version.
- I downloaded the zipped library from this page [SRF08 Ultra Sonic Range Finder](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/SonarSrf08)
- I imported the library into the arduino IDE. For this, I had to unpack the .zip and rename the folder of the library because arduino complained about non-ascii characters. I just called the enclosing folder "arduinoSRFmaster" without dashes. After that it let me import the library the usual way:

  [image: How to Install a Library]
- After that I copied your code into a new sketch and hit Ctrl + R to compile and verify. It compiled just fine:

  [image: Successfull compiling]

(Picture updated for compiling against MEGA)

**Please provide more information, like yor OS, Arduino Version, where you got the SRF Library from etc. if that didn't help.**

Comment: It seems you have compiled for UNO, maybe the problem is specific to Mega?

Comment: There should not be anything specific to the UNO in the code, therefore that should not be any issue. I updated my answer anyway.

Comment: Sometimes OS might be a problem. When I used BLE library from Redbearlabs. And compile it I got an error message on Ubuntu. But when I did the same procedure with windows I was able to compile my sketch.

Comment: I'll try it on Ubuntu and Mac and update my answer